# format.js and format.json in same respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im a little bit confused about how both can work together `format.js` and `format.json`

I have an ajax request and this is the controller action:

```
def import_contacts_submit
    @new_file = ContactsFile.new(contacts_file_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      @new_file.save
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @new_file.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } if @new_file.has_errors?
    end
  end
```

as it is, only the `format.js` seems to be working, because the error callback I have in the ajax request never runs. But if I move the `format.json` above the `format.js` then the error callback in ajax triggers and the `format.js` never runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails determines the format to take, by reading the `Accept` header of the http request:

Example:

```
  def test
      f.js {
        render js: "Hello World"
      }
      f.json {
        render json: { foo: :bar }
      }
    end
```

```sh
curl localhost:3000/test -H 'Accept: application/json'
{"foo":"bar"}%

curl localhost:3000/test -H 'Accept: application/javascript'
Hello World%
```

Try changing the header `accept` in your XHR call, e.g. when using `fetch`:

```js
fetch(url, { 
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
})
```

Similar in jquery's.ajax or raw XHtmlRequest.

**Update** Rails Content negotiation:

Rails has a heuristic for determine the format. Check the Doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/MimeNegotiation.html#method-i-formats

`formats.first` will be taken as the "format" for the request, and the order is like this. First rule will "win":

1. a parameter called "format", e.g. ?format=json
2. Accept header
3. path suffix, e.g. `/foo/bar.json`
4. When XHR -> Always js
5. otherwise HTML

Comment: I still have the doubt... So if I do not specify the `accept` then rails will run only the first format it encounters?

Comment: @svelandiag I've updated the answer with details about Rails content negotiation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `Accept` header you can explicitly state format in url:

```
some_path/to/import_contacts_submit.js
some_path/to/import_contacts_submit.json
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra tip